# Is $A^{-1}+B^tAB$ invertible if $A$ and $B$ are invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ and $B$ be invertible matrices of the same size with $A$ symmetric and $B$ skew-symmetric. Is $A^{-1}+B^tAB$ invertible as well? And, if it is, can its inverse be expressed in terms of $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Why do you think such a thing would be true? Unless you have some argument for its plausibility, there is no point in trying to prove a random identity.

Comment: I'm trying to invert a block matrix and this thing showed up as the Schur complement.

Comment: Since $A^{-1}+B^tAB=-A^{-1}(B^{-1}+A)B(B^{-1}+A)^tB$, you are essentially asking whether $B^{-1}+A$ is always invertible. I think the answer should be clear.

Comment: Amusingly, that is the Schur complement for the block matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} {\bf A}^{-1} & {\bf B} \\ {\bf B} & {\bf A}^{-1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 1):

Try $A=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1}$ and $B=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$.

Comment: Can you still provide a counter example with A positive definite?

Comment: @UgoIaba If $A\succ0$, then $A^{-1}$ and $B^tAB$ are positive definite too. Hence their sum is invertible.